# Cloudfront Origin Group detect failver using Lambda@Edge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

**My setup:**

I have a Cloudfront Origin Group where Bucket A is a primary bucket and Bucket B is a secondary bucket. Lambda@Edge is added on `origin-request` to do a certain process.

Whenever a request comes to Cloudfront, my Lambda@Edge modifies it to match the folder structure of my bucket and returns file accordingly.

If Bucket A doesn't have a certain file it throws an error and Cloudfront failover requests the file from Bucket B. Bucket B doesn't have the same structure as Bucket it, it should return the file from unmodified file path in the bucket.

**Example:**

My Original Request: `/somefile.html`
Lambda@Edge modifies this request to get the file from Bucket A to: `/en/somefile.html`

If Bucket A doesn't have this somefile.html then this request goes to Bucket B. It should return file from the originally requested path: `/somefile.html` and not `/en/somefile.html`

The above scenario is very simple, my original scenario is much complex. Basically Bucket A file path is processed path while Bucket B should return file from an originally requested path.

**What I want:**

Using Lambda@Edge how can I detect if the request is on Bucket A or bucket B?

**What I have tried:**

- I tried adding certain header in request headers and check if the header exists then its request to Bucket B. But this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Take a look inside `event.Records[0].cf.request.origin.s3.domainName` inside the Lambda function. It should be the bucket's endpoint hostname, e.g. `example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com` so you could use that to differentiate between first and second origins.

Comment: Sure, this is one thing I was trying but was not sure about it. Thanks for this 

Comment: FYI, I am not getting `event.Records[0].cf.request.origin.s3.domainName` but `event.Records[0].cf.request.origin.custom.domainName`. It seems to be doing job. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hostname of the origin that CloudFront will try to contact after an origin-request trigger returns control can be found in one of two places.

If you are using what CloudFront calls an *S3 origin* (the REST interface to S3) it will be here:

```
event.Records[0].cf.request.origin.s3.domainName
```

If you are using what CloudFront calls a *custom origin* -- which includes S3 website hosting endpoints as well as any other origin server that isn't S3 REST, it's here:

```
event.Records[0].cf.request.origin.custom.domainName
```

These can be used to determine which of two origins in an origin group will receive the request, next.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html#lambda-event-structure-request