# Lambda script to direct to fallback S3 domain subfolder when not found

Tags: amazon-s3

As per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49812706/serving-a-multitude-of-static-sites-from-a-wildcard-domain-in-aws), and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59587213/point-subfolder-in-s3-bucket-to-buildmywebsite-domain) the following piece of code, allows me to point a subfolder in a S3 bucket to my domain.

However in instances where the subdomain is not found, I get the following error message:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>2CE9B7837081C817</RequestId>
<HostId>
T3p7mzSYztPhXetUu7GHPiCFN6l6mllZgry+qJWYs+GFOKMjScMmRNUpBQdeqtDcPMN3qSYU/Fk=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I would not like it to display this error message, instead in instances like this I would like to serve from another S3 bucket subdomain (i.e. `example-bucket.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/error`) for example where the user will be greeted with a fancy error message. So therefore in a situation where a S3 bucket subfolder is not found, it should fall back to there. How do I accomplish this by changing the node function below.

```
'use strict';

// if the end of incoming Host header matches this string, 
// strip this part and prepend the remaining characters onto the request path,
// along with a new leading slash (otherwise, the request will be handled
// with an unmodified path, at the root of the bucket)

const remove_suffix = '.example.com';

// provide the correct origin hostname here so that we send the correct 
// Host header to the S3 website endpoint

const origin_hostname = 'example-bucket.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'; // see comments, below

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;
    const host_header = headers.host[0].value;

    if(host_header.endsWith(remove_suffix))
    {
        // prepend '/' + the subdomain onto the existing request path ("uri")
        request.uri = '/' + host_header.substring(0,host_header.length - remove_suffix.length) + request.uri;
    }

    // fix the host header so that S3 understands the request
    headers.host[0].value = origin_hostname;

    // return control to CloudFront with the modified request
    return callback(null,request);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lambda@Edge function is an *origin request* trigger -- it runs after the CloudFront cache is checked and a cache miss has occurred, immediately before the request (as it stands after being modified by the trigger code) is sent to the origin server.  By the time the response arrives from the origin, this code has finished and can't be used to modify the response.

There are several solutions, including some that are conceptually valid but extremely inefficient.  Still, I'll mention those as well as the cleaner/better solutions, in the interest of thoroughness.

Lambda@Edge has [4 possible trigger points](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-cloudfront-trigger-events.html):

- viewer-request - when request first arrives at CloudFront, before the cache is checked; fires for every request.
- origin-request - after the request is confirmed to be a cache miss, but before the request is sent to the origin server; only fires in cache misses.
- origin-response - after a response (whether success or error) is returned from the origin server, but before the response is potentially stored in the cache and returned to the viewer; if this trigger modifies the response, the modified response will be stored in the CloudFront cache if cacheable, and returned to the viewer; only fires on cache misses
- viewer-response - inmediately before the response is returned to the viewer, whether from the origin or cache; fires for every non-error response, unless that response was spontaneously emitted by a viewer-request trigger, or is the result of a custom error document that sets the status code to 200 (a definite anti-pattern, but still possible), or is a CloudFront-generated HTTP to HTTPS redirect.

Any of the trigger points can assume control of the signal flow, [generate its own spontaneous response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-generated-response-examples), and thus change what CloudFront would have ordinarily done -- e.g. if you generate a response directly from an origin-request trigger, CloudFront doesn't actually contact the origin... so what you could *theoretically* do is check S3 in the origin-request trigger to see if the request will succeed and generate a custom error response, instead.  The AWS Javascript SDK is automatically bundled into the Lambda@Edge environmemt.  Technically legitimate, this is probably a terrible idea in almost any case, since it will increase both costs and latency due to extra "look-ahead" requests to S3.

Another option is to write a separate origin-response trigger to check for errors, and if occurs, replace it with a customized response from the trigger code.  But this idea also qualifies as non-viable, since that trigger will fire for all responses to cache misses, whether success or failure, increasing costs and latency, wasting time for a majority of cases.

A better idea (cost, performance, ease-of-use) is [CloudFront Custom Error Pages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-error-pages.html), which allows you to define a specific HTML document that CloudFront will use for every error matching the specified code (e.g. 403 for access denied, as in the original question).  CloudFront can also change that 403 to a 404 when handling those errors.  This requires that you do several things when the source of the error file is a bucket:

- create a second CloudFront origin pointing to the bucket
- create a new cache behavior that routes exactly that one path (e.g. `/shared/errors/not-found.html`) to the error file over to the new origin (this means you can't use that path on any of the subdomains -- it will always go directly to the error file any time it's requested)
- configure a CloudFront custom error response for code 403 to use the path `/shared/errors/not-found.html`.
- set Error Caching Minimum TTL to 0, at least while testing, to avoid some frustration for yourself.  See [my write-up on this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35541525/1695906) but disregard the part where I said *"Leave `Customize Error Response` set to `No`"*.

But... that may or may not be needed, since S3's web hosting feature also includes optional [Custom Error Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CustomErrorDocSupport.html) support.  You'll need to create a single HTML file in your original bucket, enable the web site hosting feature on the bucket, and change the CloudFront Origin Domain Name to the bucket's web site hosting endpoint, which is in the S3 console but takes the form of`${bucket}.s3-website.${region}.amazonaws.com`.  In some regions, the hostname might have a dash `-` rather than a dot `.` after `s3-website` for legacy reasons, but the dot format should work in any region.

---

I almost hesitate mention one other option that comes to mind, since it's fairly advanced and I fear the description might seem quite convoluted... but you also could do the following, and it would be pretty slick, since it would allow you to potentiallh generate a custom HTML page for each erroneous URL requested.

Create a CloudFront [Origin Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/high_availability_origin_failover.html) with your main bucket as the primary and a second, empty, "placeholder" bucket as secondary.  The only purpose served by the second bucket is so that we give CloudFront a valid name that it plans to connect to, even though we won't actually connect to it, as may become clear, below.

When request fails to the primary origin, matching one of the configured error status codes, the secondary origin is contacted.  This is intended for handling the case when an origin fails, but we can leverage it for our purposes, because before actually contacting the failover origin, the same origin request trigger fires a second time.

> If the primary origin returns an HTTP status code that you’ve configured for failover, the Lambda function is triggered again, when CloudFront re-routes the request to the second origin.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/high_availability_origin_failover.html#concept_origin_groups.lambda

(It would be more accurate to say "...when CloudFront *is preparing to re-route* the request to the second origin," because the trigger fires first.)

When the trigger fires a second time, the specific reason it fires isn't preserved, but there is [a way to identify whether you're running in the first or second invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59188101/1695906): one of these two values will contain the hostname of the origin server CloudFront is preparing to contact:

```
event.Records[0].cf.request.origin.s3.domainName     # S3 rest endpoints
event.Records[0].cf.request.origin.custom.domainName # non-S3 origins and S3 website-hosting endpoints
```

So we can test the appropriate value (depending on origin type) in the trigger code, looking for the name of the second "placeholder" bucket. If it's there, bypass the current logic and generate the 404 response from inside the Lambda function.   This could be dynamic/customized HTML, such as with the page URI or perhaps one that varies depending on whether `/` or some other page is requested.  As noted above, spontaneously generating a response from an origin-request trigger prevents CloudFronr from actually contacting the origin.  Generated responses from an origin-request trigger are limited to 1MB but that should be beyond sufficient for this use case.

Comment: Hi Michael. Many thanks for your detailed response. I have decided to go down the `Cloudfront Custom Error Pages` route, but I don't understand the following step: `create a new cache behavior that routes exactly that one path (e.g. /shared/errors/not-found.html) to the error file over to the new origin (this means you can't use that path on any of the subdomains -- it will always go directly to the error file any time it's requested)`. Can you please explain to me in a bit more detail?  I have created the second origin here: https://imgur.com/a/A10e1KI (one with the `_errors` origin id).

Comment: I set up the cache behaviour as follows, https://imgur.com/a/bjWqElY but it redirects all the "correct" subdomain links to the error page. I am unsure about where to configure the cache behaviour to do otherwse.

Comment: You have set the new cache behavior to match path pattern `*` -- all requests, but path pattern for the new cache behavior should just be the path to the error file, e.g. `/shared/errors/not-found.html`. Also you don't need a separate cache behavior unless the error file is in a different bucket, and you should not set Origin Path on the new origin.  That doesn't do what you want.  (CloudFront adds the value from Origin Path to the beginning of the request URI before sending each request to the origin.  It's useful only if all requests to the origin need a static string prepended to the path.)

Comment: Hi Michael, sorry to disturb again, but I have come across a related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59986729/fallback-to-s3-website-subfolder-for-angular-spa. Would appreciate your advice if possible? Thanks